# Ambiguous reference to member subscript error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, beacon

```
var centralManager: CBCentralManager!

@nonobjc func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    **if let centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey]** {
        NSLog("UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey = \(centralManagerIdentifiers)")
    }
```

I am getting an error where I do the optional binding of CentralManagerIdentifiers,
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which version of swift you are using?

Comment: it's `launchOptions?[.bluetoothCentrals]`

Comment: Your method header is written in the form of Swift 2. Do not hide the warning with `@nonobjc`. You need to fix the method header for Swift 3 (or 4?), and possibly some other things.

Comment: Is that you solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks! that seems correct, I think I need to use swift 3 and change other parts of the code too.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Try this.

```
if let centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals] {
            NSLog("UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey = \(centralManagerIdentifiers)")
        }
```